# PHP exec fails to recognize PHP hash

Tags: php, perl, hash

I'm generating a hash in my Perl file and when I run the script form console everything is fine. If I run the same script via PHP my hash seems to be empty.

In PHP:

```
exec("perl perl/test.pl", $output);
print_r($output);
```

In my Perl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $filename = 'test.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename);

my %tc;

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;

    if ($row =~ /someregex/) {
        $tc{$1} = $2;
    }

}

my $size = keys %tc;
print $size;

print Dumper(\%tc);
```

When I run it in console it has a size of 1 using this code piece and the dumper shows the right content. When I print it out in PHP it has a size of 0 and gives back an empty array.

The PHP does run the Perl script as if I only give back some simple data, the PHP shows it.

I would appreciate every helping answer. Thanks!

Comment: try specifying the full path to `perl/test.pl`

Comment: did you try to use `shell_exec` instead of `exec` ?

Comment: Try to use an absolute path when executing the script and make sure that the user, which the system is using to run your PHP, has the correct file permissions.

Comment: It runs the script, I don't need full path; if I write out only a single string or array in my perl, the PHP shows it correctly. I tried to use shell_exec but same output.

Comment: the test.txt needs to be full path'd, as the CWD would be different running through php

Comment: Okay, I got what happened. I needed full path to the file as it tried to open from the folder of the php file. I gave full path and now it's working. Thank you guys!

Comment: ^^ what I said :)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you even need to do this? What is Perl doing that you can't do in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the relative path using the script's dir rather than the current work dir, change

```
my $filename = 'test.txt';
```

to

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

my $filename = "$RealBin/test.txt";
```